# Hide table content without nesting it in a column

Tags: html, css, html-table

```
<table style="display:none">
    unhidden text
    <tr>
        <td>
            hidden text
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Only the text within the `td` is hidden, despite `display: none` being applied to the whole table. Can I get the `unhidden text` to be hidden also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table style must only work for those tags that are recognizable table tags...

Here are a couple options.. Using a `span` tag or a `div` tag which works for all elements inside it.

```
<table style="display:none">
  <span style="display:none">unhidden text</span>
  <tr>
    <td>
        hidden text
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

or in my opinion a better solution.

```
<div style="display:none">
  <table>
    unhidden text
   <tr>
    <td>
        hidden text
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<table>` nodes are only to contain specific elements, which does not include text nodes.
Likewise the same for `<tr>` nodes.

The html table [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html) shows this.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid. You are not allowed to have text nodes as a direct child of a `table` element.

Browsers typically correct your HTML, so they interpret it like this:

```
unhidden text
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        hidden text
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, `unhidden text` was moved out of the `table`.

So you should place "unhidden text" outside of the `table`, and, if you need a styling hook etc., use a `div` (or a more appropriate element) for it:

```
<div>unhidden text</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      hidden text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```